# how to Extract a particular field from the return string

Tags: xml, go

Was able to get a return string after hitting the service.
String looks as below,

```
<details>
<unitdetails>
<number>11</number>
<name>John</name>
<sal>20000</sal>
</unitdetails>
<deptdetails>
<number>10</number>     <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
<amt>1000</amt>
<date>20211407</date>
</deptdetails>
<divdetails>
<number>200</number>
<status>Available</status>
<value>10</value>
</divdetails>
</details>
```

From the above output string I need to extract only the number '10' under the deptdetails.

Comment: I'll remove the goland tag, nothing specific to Goland, instead I'll add xml

Comment: What have you tried? Show your code. What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Please accept one of the answers if they helped you solving the task. It will help others that face similar challenges in the future

Answer (score 3):

Basically you would deserialize like in other languages also. So you would create a struct containing other structs and then deserialize.

See eg https://tutorialedge.net/golang/parsing-xml-with-golang/ for an example on how to do this

```
type Details struct {
    XMLName     xml.Name `xml:"details"`
    Text        string   `xml:",chardata"`
    Unitdetails struct {
        Text   string `xml:",chardata"`
        Number string `xml:"number"`
        Name   string `xml:"name"`
        Sal    string `xml:"sal"`
    } `xml:"unitdetails"`
    Deptdetails struct {
        Text   string `xml:",chardata"`
        Number string `xml:"number"`
        Amt    string `xml:"amt"`
        Date   string `xml:"date"`
    } `xml:"deptdetails"`
    Divdetails struct {
        Text   string `xml:",chardata"`
        Number string `xml:"number"`
        Status string `xml:"status"`
        Value  string `xml:"value"`
    } `xml:"divdetails"`
} 

var details Details
xml.Unmarshal(byteValue, &details)
details.DeptDetails.Number // access
```

This is just a quick (and untested!) writedown to give you an idea

Comment: If only a single value is needed, then the entire data structure doesn't need to be duplicated in Go structs.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the input from Sascha,I created a simple program for your scenario as follows :

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type Details struct {
    XMLName     xml.Name `xml:"details"`
    Text        string   `xml:",chardata"`
    Unitdetails struct {
        Text   string `xml:",chardata"`
        Number string `xml:"number"`
        Name   string `xml:"name"`
        Sal    string `xml:"sal"`
    } `xml:"unitdetails"`
    Deptdetails struct {
        Text   string `xml:",chardata"`
        Number string `xml:"number"`
        Amt    string `xml:"amt"`
        Date   string `xml:"date"`
    } `xml:"deptdetails"`
    Divdetails struct {
        Text   string `xml:",chardata"`
        Number string `xml:"number"`
        Status string `xml:"status"`
        Value  string `xml:"value"`
    } `xml:"divdetails"`
}

func main() {

    var payload = []byte(`
    <details><unitdetails><number>11</number><name>John</name><sal>20000</sal></unitdetails><deptdetails><number>10</number><amt>1000</amt><date>20211407</date></deptdetails><divdetails><number>200</number><status>Available</status><value>10</value></divdetails></details>

`)

    var details Details
    xml.Unmarshal(payload, &details)

    fmt.Println(details)
    fmt.Println(details.Deptdetails.Number)
}
```

Output:

```
{{ details}  { 11 John 20000} { 10 1000 20211407} { 200 Available 10}}
10
```